# Adding MarkInfo entry element to logical structure of a PDF file using Aspose dll's

Tags: c#, pdf, dll, aspose, aspose.pdf

I am using the most recent Aspose.PDF DLL in Visual Studio with the appropriate (in the code applied) license.

For my conversion from pdf files to pdfa types I use the following code:

```
Aspose.Pdf.Document pdf = new Aspose.Pdf.Document(pdfPath);     
bool converted = pdf.Convert(temptext, PdfFormat.PDF_A_1A, ConvertErrorAction.None);
```

Now I receive the following errors, extracted from the temptext txtfile:

```
<Problem Severity="Error" Clause="6.8.3.3" Convertable="True">Catalog shall have struct tree root entry</Problem>
<Problem Severity="Error" Clause="6.8.2.2" Convertable="True">Catalog shall have MarkInfo entry</Problem>
```

Now to get a MarkInfo entry into the structure of my PDF file, I am supposed to be able to add elements to the catalog or root structure ( I am not sure exactly) which will give me the ability to create this entry tag to the logical structure of the PDF file.
Then these two errors will be avoided and the PDFa file will be converted correctly.

I noticed PDFSharp had a solution for this problem with their dll’s in the following way:

```
PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument doc = PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open(pdfPath);
PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDictionary structureTreeRoot = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDictionary(doc);
structureTreeRoot.Elements["/StructElem"] = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfName("/Entry1"); 
PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfArray array = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfArray(doc);
doc.Internals.AddObject(structureTreeRoot);
doc.Internals.Catalog.Elements["/StructTreeRoot"] = PdfInternals.GetReference(structureTreeRoot);
```

I  want to only use the Aspose dll. Does anyone know how I can apply this with aspose dll?

Comment: Please use code blocks to display code

Comment: Answer: Apparently this isn't supported by Aspose yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Aspose.Pdf does not support to add MarkInfo entry in logical structure of PDF. Please check the [forum thread](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/642723/642723.aspx) for similar question.

My name is Tilal Ahmad and I am developer evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Originally the question was based on failure on PDFa conversions. But I got a direct answer from aspose to handle that.